# How to make a background fill the screen, but stay centered in a responsive design

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a website. It is a single page website and the landing page has a bit of text along with a big background image. It looks like this:

[image]

It all works perfectly and this is the code that I used for it.

index:

```
<div class="banner" id="header">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 text-center">
                <div class="center-block">
                    <h1 class="landing-head">Welcome</h1>
                    </br >
                    <p class="landing-text">A portfolio</p>
                    </br >
                    <a class="nostyle-link" data-scroll="" href="#about">
                        <div id="go-button">
                            <p>Discover</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


/*------ background and divider styles ------*/
.banner {
    height:100%;
    width: 100%
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    -o-background-size:cover;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position: top left, center center;
    background-repeat: repeat, no-repeat;
    z-index: -1;
}

.content {
    height: 60% !important;
    background-color: white;
}

#header {
    background-image: url("../images/background1_2_2.jpg");
}

#divider {
    background-image: url("../images/divider.jpg");
}
```

Now the problem is that when I run it in responsive mode, the background image does not scale or center, it just stays the same resulting in this:

[image]

As you can see the image is not centered, but the view window is just moved over it rather. Can I solve this?

Comment: Did you try `background-attachment:fixed;`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
background-position: top left, center center;
```

to

```
background-position: center center;
```

Comment: This worked. I feel so very, very stupid now haha :p I will approve your answer in 8 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Just to put this in your header id tag and it will centered the image in responsive mode.

```
#header {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-size:cover;
}
```